# How to set umask for daemon only in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: services, aws, support, umask

I am working on OS hardening tasks. Need to set umask value for all the daemon processes running in the ubuntu system. It would be great if someone can share the steps.
**Note:** umask need not be set for the entire system which will be done by adding umask value in ~./profile file.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is the ubuntu version being used - guiverc

Comment: Please understand the question properly. I have asked how to set umask in ubuntu version 18.04. And you are deviating the whole question?
Kindly stick to the context of the question asked - guiverc

Comment: Can you please suggest the answer?